# How can I update a SQLite3 database if text has been changed on my website?

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

I'm currently writing a program for a school project. Essentially I have got a table on my website and each individual value in the table can be edited. However, I am wondering is it possible to check if any changes have been made in the table then push those changes to the database by pressing a button.

This is how I have made my table data editable via the web page.

```
<td style="text-align:center" <div contenteditable>{{row[0]}}</td>
```

Again I am using Python, Flask and SQLite3.

Answer (score 0):

Consider you want to edit the Marks for all the student.

So in your HTML page, wrap the entire table inside HTML form tag.
Once you submit the form, all the data will be passed to the Flask.

```
<form>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" name="name_reg1" value="Student Name 1"></td>
      <td><input type="number" name="mark_reg1" value="45"></td>
      <td><input type="number" name="mark_reg1" value="26"></td>
      <td><input type="number" name="mark_reg1" value="87"></td>
      <td><input type="number" name="mark_reg1" value="68"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" name="name_reg2" value="Student Name 2"></td>
      <td><input type="number" name="mark_reg2" value="56"></td>
      <td><input type="number" name="mark_reg2" value="64"></td>
      <td><input type="number" name="mark_reg2" value="77"></td>
      <td><input type="number" name="mark_reg2" value="82"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <input type="submit" name="Submit">
</form>
```

you can easily identify the mark with register number.
Now you can write the SQL query to add the data to the database.